# How to evaluate this transition function when converting from PDA to CFG?

Tags: finite-automata

I'm trying to convert a PDA to CFG. What is the production in the below transition. I'm stuck here.

$$δ(q_1,ε,Z_0)=(q_2,Z_0)$$

Also pls state detailed rules or rules for specific situations as the general rules doesnt seem to answer what to do in special situations or exceptions. Thanks)